# Почему cirilic шрифт применился и к английскому шрифту?

Tags: html, css

Сверстал от нечего делать (просто так макет) трехколночный и применил для кирилицы шрифт `font-family: 'Bad Script', cursive;` но он не должен отображаться для английских latin шрифтов а должен выводится обычным , есть варианты что бы английский текст выводить другим шрифтом ?
Это пример : http://www.maxim1978.0fees.us/

```css
*{
  margin:0; padding:0; text-decoration:none; list-style:none;
}
.clear{
 display:block; clear:both;
}
.clear:after{
 content:"";  display:block; clear:both;
}
html,body p{
 font-family: 'Bad Script', cursive; line-height:20px;
}
header,footer{
 display:block; width:80%; margin:3px auto; border:1px solid rgba(200,0,0,0); min-height:100px;
}
menu{
 display:table; margin:3px auto; width:80%; border-bottom:5px solid rgba(200,0,0,0);margin-bottom:10px; border-radius:10%;
}
menu ul{
 display:table-row;
}
menu ul li{
 display:table-cell; vertical-align:bottom; text-align:center;
}
menu ul li a{
 display:table-cell; width:1000px; height:50px; vertical-align:middle; color:rgb(0,0,0);
}
.aside,.article,.ads{
 float:left; box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
main{
 display:block; width:80%; margin:3px auto;
}
main .aside,.article,.ads{
 background:rgba(255,255,255,1); border-bottom:1px solid rgba(200,0,0,0);
}
.aside{
 width:20%; min-height:140px;
}
.aside h2,.article h2,.ads h2{
 font-family: 'Marck Script', cursive; color:rgb(0,0,0); text-align:center; background:#fff; padding:10px 0;border-bottom:1px solid rgba(200,200,200,.3);
}

.ads{
 width:20%; min-height:170px;
}
.article{
 width:59%; min-height:200px; border-left:1px solid rgba(200,0,0,0);border-right:1px solid rgba(200,0,0,0); margin:0 .5%;
}
.article .post{
 margin:20px 10px; background:-webkit-linear-gradient(#fff,#fefefe,#fff); border-bottom:3px dotted #ccc;position:relative;
}
.article .post img{
 width:40%; float:left; margin:5px;
}
.full_paper{
 position:absolute; bottom:10px; right:20px;
}
.article .post p{
 padding:0 40px; margin:20px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta charset="utf8">
<title>Резиновый сайт</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marck+Script&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bad+Script&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<header></header>
<menu> 
 <ul> 
  <li><a href="">Главная</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Гостевая</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Примеры скриптов</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Статьи</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Портфолио</a></li>
  <li><a href="">О нас</a></li>
 </ul>
</menu>
<main class="clear"> 
<div class="aside">
 <h2>Наше меню</h2>
</div>
<div class="article">
<h2>Статьи</h2>
<div class="post"> 
 <h3>Название статьи</h3>
 <img src="images/lorem.jpg" alt="lorem isum" />
 <p>Сайт рыбатекст поможет дизайнеру, верстальщику, вебмастеру сгенерировать несколько абзацев более менее осмысленного текста рыбы на русском языке, а начинающему оратору отточить навык публичных выступлений в домашних условиях. При создании генератора мы использовали небезызвестный универсальный код речей. Текст генерируется абзацами случайным образом от двух до десяти предложений в абзаце, что позволяет сделать текст более привлекательным и живым для визуально-слухового восприятия.
</p>

<p>По своей сути рыбатекст является альтернативой традиционному lorem ipsum, который вызывает у некторых клиентов недоумение при попытках прочитать рыбу текст. В отличии от lorem ipsum, текст рыба на русском языке наполнит любой макет непонятным смыслом и придаст неповторимый колорит советских времен.</p>
<a href="" class="full_paper">Читать далее...</a>
</div>
<div class="post">
<h3>Ещё название статьи </h3>
<img src="images/lorem1.jpg" alt="lorem ipsum" />
<p> 
Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов.
</p>
 <p>Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
<a href="" class="full_paper">Читать далее...</a>
</div>
<div class="post">
<h3>Ещё одно название статьи</h3>
<img src="images/loremipsum.jpg" alt="" />
<p>
Давно выяснено, что при оценке дизайна и композиции читаемый текст мешает сосредоточиться. Lorem Ipsum используют потому, что тот обеспечивает более или менее стандартное заполнение шаблона, а также реальное распределение букв и пробелов в абзацах, которое не получается при простой дубликации.
</p>
<p>
 Многие программы электронной вёрстки и редакторы HTML используют Lorem Ipsum в качестве текста по умолчанию, так что поиск по ключевым словам "lorem ipsum" сразу показывает, как много веб-страниц всё ещё дожидаются своего настоящего рождения. За прошедшие годы текст Lorem Ipsum получил много версий. Некоторые версии появились по ошибке, некоторые - намеренно (например, юмористические варианты
</p>
<a href="" class="full_paper">Читать далее...</a>
</div>
<div class="post">
<h3>English version Lorem Ipsum</h3>
<img src="images/50-lorem-ipsum.jpg" alt="" />
<p>Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat.
</p> 
<p>
Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui.
</p>
<a href="" class="full_paper">Read more...</a>
</div>
</div> <!--article-->
<div class="ads">
<h2>Реклама</h2>
</div>
</main>
<footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С точки зрения css и шрифтов кириллица ничем не отличается от любого другого алфавита, там вообще нет инструментов для разделения на этой основе.

Вы можете найти шрифт, в котором есть *только* кириллические символы, а в качестве запасного указать тот, в котором есть латиница.

Comment: так в этом шрифте нету вообще поддержки latin , а работает

Comment: Ну как же нет, вы прямо в ссылке её указываете: `<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bad+Script&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`. Но если убрать из ссылки, ничего не изменится: шрифты, в которых есть *только* кириллица очень редки и данный шрифт не из их числа.

Comment: Да и на странице шрифта явно видно, что латиница там есть: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Bad+Script

Comment: точно .... thanks buddy